# How to install Olivetti NomadJet 100S on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, usb, drivers, printer

I have printer Olivetti NomadJet 100S. When I plugged USB to computer, drivers were installed automatically. In popup about installing driver there was mentioned correct model but in `Devices and printers` it's in category `Unspecified`. In device manager I can see `USB Printing support` driver and no warning triangle is shown so it should be working.

How is it possible to move the printer from category `Unspecified` to category `Printers`?

Official drivers which I found was from Windows 3.1 till Windows XP. I tried to install the driver for Windows XP, but it does not help.
In [Amazon](https://www.amazon.de/-/en/Olivetti-Inkjet-A4-2-0ppm-600dpi-Centr/product-reviews/B000ALKYZ0) website I found that it should work with drivers for Tally t110 or Olivetti JP50 on Windows 8.1. Unfortunatelly I could not find those drivers to test it.

Comment: Windows XP (32-bit) printer drivers are incompatible with 64-but versions of Windows and in general any modern version of Windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Olivetti and Tally printers you mentioned (I used a Tally many years ago) are very old.

It is really unlikely modern Windows will have drivers for them.

Try to set them up as generic text printers and try printing monospaced text.

If that does not work, you need newer printers.

Comment: Thank you, when I set it up as generic text printer, it came alive. It has dried cartridge as expected so white page came out.

Comment: Thanks for the update.

Answer (score 1):

The last drivers I could find for this printer were for Windows 2000 or XP.
They cannot be used on Windows 10.

I suggest creating a Windows XP virtual machine where to install
the printer and driver.

Some driver sites that claim having a good driver:

- [Easy Driver Updater](http://www.easydriverupdater.com/download/olivetti-nomadjet-printer-s/34199/7229F14A6BB6D15794AC8B3855855660)
- [PcDrivers.Guru](https://it.pcdrivers.guru/related/nomad+jet+100/)

I can't vouch for any of the above.

Comment: This solution also came to my mind.  Solution to print anything without programs also installed in WinXP is print in Windows 10 to PDF and in WinXP is PDF reader enough. Solution should be working but install virtual WinXP just to be able to print something is not the best solution - 4GB printer driver is quite big.